# deploying j2me application on old handsets

Tags: java-me, lwuit, midp, j2mepolish, wma

I was to develop a simple j2me application for microworks. The application is to send sms.

But I found that most of the mobile phone they carry are very simple and even some of them don't have Bluetooth, infrared, browser. How to make it work out?

We can assume configuration as nokia 2100, nokia 1616. How am I supposed to deploy my app on such handsets?

Comment: What kind of old mobile phones are we talking about here?

Comment: i dont have the exact model number but management team told me those mobile phone dont have Infrarred, Bluetooth, browser.... we can assume configuration as nokia 2100, nokia 1616

Comment: As long as these handsets can support MIDP (hopefully 2), and JSR 205 then you're good to go.

Comment: but how m i supposed to deploy my app on such handsets

Comment: The old school way :) Via datacable and Nokia Suite. If you're lucky to have browsers on some devices then a download Wap site won't hurt either.

Comment: thanks for editing question.... but still i am not getting what i need

Answer (score 2):

OTA is required to work on every MIDP mobile device, just navigate with the device browser to the jad URL and click it.